# OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found?

Tags: python, deep-learning

Firstly sorry, my grammer might be bad. And if I missed any solutions in here, you can give me url, but I did not find any proper one for this case.

I'm taking a course about deep learning, and they provide us to this code. However there was an error which I encounter only. This is the main.py;

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import torch
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from envs import create_atari_env
from model import ActorCritic
from train import train
from testt import test
import my_optim

# Gathering all the parameters (that we can modify to explore)
class Params():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lr = 0.0001
        self.gamma = 0.99
        self.tau = 1.
        self.seed = 1
        self.num_processes = 16
        self.num_steps = 20
        self.max_episode_length = 10000
        self.env_name = 'Breakout-v0'

# Main run
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
params = Params()
torch.manual_seed(params.seed)
env = create_atari_env(params.env_name)
shared_model = ActorCritic(env.observation_space.shape[0], env.action_space)
shared_model.share_memory()
optimizer = my_optim.SharedAdam(shared_model.parameters(), lr=params.lr)
optimizer.share_memory()
processes = []
p = mp.Process(target=test, args=(params.num_processes, params, shared_model))
p.start()
processes.append(p)
for rank in range(0, params.num_processes):
    p = mp.Process(target=train, args=(rank, params, shared_model, optimizer))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

Is it caused by "from envs import create_atari_env". Because after install create_atari_env, after I install it. And also I do not use any paths in scripts.

Error;

> ****\lib\ctypes_*init*_.py line 426 in LoadLibrary self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)   OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is often caused in relation to `path`, for example, which requires the correct use of `double-slashes`, `forward-slashes` or `raw-strings` but since you mentioned this wasn't your case I believe the root cause of this error is by

```
import torch
```

There are known cases of PyTorch breaking DLL loading on specific `Python` and `PyTorch` versions (applies to `PyTorch 1.5.0 on Python 3.7` specifically). Once you run import torch, any further DLL loads will fail. So if you're using PyTorch and loading your own DLLs you'll have to rearrange your code to import all DLLs first and then `import torch`.

Comment: So if I downgrade my `torch` for this case, will it solve? Or should I use `VM with Ubuntu`, because if I'm not wrong `gym` actually do not support `Windows`.

Comment: yes you can try it. It shouldnt be that hard- just use pip install <packageNameWithVersion>

Comment: Can I ask you another question about A3C?

Comment: sure. If its an extensive question then edit and add to your question

Comment: ```self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(num_inputs, 32, 3, stride=2, padding=1)
self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, 3, stride=2, padding=1)
self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, 3, stride=2, padding=1)
self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, 3, stride=2, padding=1)
self.lstm = nn.LSTMCell(32 * 3 * 3, 256)```
As you can see there is 4 convolution layers. Then we used lstm layer. But I could not find simple formula for calculate this value (32 * 3 * 3). Do you know it?

Comment: Hmm. I really dont understand the context here. Please consider asking this as another question and then you can provide me the link here to have a look at

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62724776/torch-lstmcell-method here.